# Incorrect page number in the footer of the MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I have document with some sections. In every section I have current page number and total number of section pages which placed in the footer.
Problem: I have two lines on the third page, but page number displayed only "page 2 from 3". 
[image]

But if I add some lines (even empty) to the third page - page number in the footer become correct - "page 3 from 3".
[image]
On the picture you can see problem (I've made pages shorter in the image editor).
How can I solve it without adding additional lines?

**UPD:**
Tried to remove everything from footer, except pages (but in this case I need only one extra line for correct pages showing):
[image]

Tried added page in several ways:
[image]

Another variant:
[image]

**UPD #2**
Alt+F9 to show fields code:
[image]

Comment: It might help if you showed us the actual fields that you have in the footer.  Also, just for fun, try deleting all the other text in the footer (other than “Page *n* from *n*”) and see whether the problem goes away.

Comment: @G-Man I've update my question

Comment: Alt-F9 to show your field codes. Also, do your footers link to previous?

Comment: @chingNotCHing I've update my question with pitcure. Yes, footer links to previous. Changes in one of them duplicated in another.

Comment: Would it be ok if you at the footer Hit Ctrl-A then F9 to refresh the page numbers?

Comment: @chingNotCHing doesn't work. Even if it worked - I generate this document programaticaly with Apache POI, and can't do any manual actions. This third problem page can be different lenght. As you see - problem with page appear when content on this page - only several lines in the top. More than 5-7 lines on this page do not lead to a problem.

Comment: May be it is associated with MS Office updates? Look here https://superuser.com/a/1262227/789996