# {page} variable in Word 2016 not updating in a formula

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, field-codes

In a footer in Word 2016 (Windows 10), if I place {page} on its own, it updates correctly; however, if I place it in a formula like {={page}*2}}, it only displays the correct value on the first page and on all subsequent pages it displays the value from the first page. So if I have both placed I get a sequence like:

```
1  2  on the first page
2  2  on the second page
3  2  on the third page
4  2  on the fourth page etc.
```

I have tried renaming BuildingBlocks, Normal.dotm, uninstalling and re-installing Office, nothing works.

This error only appeared a few days ago.
But the same document with those codes works perfectly on my Mac version of Word.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem at MSO 2016. Error only appeared a few days ago. On other PC with MS Office (2013) calculations with {PAGE} works right.
Solved by:
need to go back to previous version MS Office:

1. in cmd with administrators privileges run:
   cd %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun
2. run:
   officec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.8431.2094
3. Turn off autoupdate (File->Account)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the suggestion, because I was a little nervous of rolling back to a previous version.
However, yesterday, the problem disappeared and the page numbers showed correctly as they used to do.
I am sorry, i don't know what caused the fault or what cured it.  Gremlins perhaps, driven out on Halloween????